# Проблема с потоками в JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Вопрос такой: как я должен прописать свой клас так чтобы он имел взаимодействия с многопотоками. Я просто не понимаю где имено прописать потоки.

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Racing");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1000, 800));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

```
package sample;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;

import javafx.scene.control.Alert;

public class Controller extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Thread started");
        CreateCar();
    }

    public void Move() {
        for(double i = 0; i <= 790; i++){
           // try {
               // Thread.sleep(50);
                Car.setLayoutX(i);
            //} catch (InterruptedException e) {
               // e.printStackTrace();
            //}
        }
    }

    public void CreateCar(){
        try {
            int n = Integer.parseInt(NoDField.getText());
            System.out.println(n);
            Move();

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);

            alert.setTitle("Error");
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.setContentText("Number entered incorrectly");

            alert.showAndWait();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private ImageView Car;
    @FXML
    private TextField NoDField;

    @FXML
    void ClearFielld(MouseEvent event) {
        NoDField.setText("");
    }

    @FXML
    void Start(ActionEvent event) {
        CreateCar();
    }

    @FXML
    void initialize() {

    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Line?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="800.0" prefWidth="1000.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="1000.0" style="-fx-background-color: #A9A9A9;" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <Button layoutX="14.0" layoutY="5.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#Start" prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Start" />
            <TextField fx:id="NoDField" layoutX="102.0" layoutY="5.0" onMouseClicked="#ClearFielld" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="114.0" text="Number of drivers" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <AnchorPane layoutY="156.0" prefHeight="722.0" prefWidth="1000.0" style="-fx-background-color: #FFFFFF;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <ImageView fx:id="Car" fitHeight="100.0" fitWidth="140.0" layoutX="24.0" layoutY="125.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../Machine.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
            <Label layoutX="904.0" layoutY="351.0" prefHeight="61.0" prefWidth="103.0" rotate="90.0" text="FINISH">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Calibri" size="38.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Line endX="669.0" endY="271.0" layoutX="253.0" layoutY="496.0" startX="669.0" startY="-496.0" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Я бы не рекомендовал делать делать extends Thread. Сделайте отдельный класс в котором  вам нужно многопоточное выполнение, а в контроллер отдавайте данные для обновления интерфейса.

Comment: окей а где мне нужно прописувать обьекты класа потока? вот это интересует.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaFX разрешает обновить UI только через свои потоки, иначе кидает исключение типа:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-4
```

Я бы порекомендовал бы Вам сначала взглянуть на пакет [javafx.concurrent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/fx_concurrency.htm).

Comment: То есть Thread тут не подойдёт, на сколько я понял?

Comment: Нет, если конечно не передать Task в Thread, типа new Thread(task).start();

Comment: Хорошо постараюсь что-то намудрить, спасибо вам!

Comment: У меня тепер другой вопрос есть, как для обьекта(в моем случае нужно для ImageView) fxml придать task?

Comment: В методе initialize наверное. Что Вы имеет конкретно имеет ввиду под "придать task"?

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы ImageView двигались по своему потоку(task) вот и спрашиваю, как я должен это зделать?

Comment: Через task обычно меняют property какого нибудь нода. Вы что хотите сделать с ImageView? Изменять размер?

Comment: нет я хочу изминять x - координату просто, я непонимаю как нужно прописать чтобы оно слелало 5 потоков

Comment: я скинул снизу код. вопрос как для кожного обьекта задействувать поток(task). Потому что щас он роботает через раз сначало первий обьект потом второй и так далее а я хочу чтобы все по своему

Answer (score 0):

```
@FXML
    Task<ImageView> task = new Task<ImageView>() {

        @Override
        protected ImageView call() throws Exception {
            Random step = new Random();
        int x = 24;
        while(x <= 770){
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                x += step.nextInt(10);
                car.get(i).setLayoutX(x);
            }
            Thread.sleep(50);
        }
    };
```

и ище 5 fxml обьектов

```
@FXML
    private ImageView Car1;
    @FXML
    private ImageView Car2;
    @FXML
    private ImageView Car3;
    @FXML
    private ImageView Car4;
    @FXML
    private ImageView Car5;
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm. Перейдите по этой ссылке, и там найдете Example 1-3. Вы можете использовать тот пример. То есть каждому ImageView создаете новый task. и потом binding'ом через progressProperty() меняете значение layoutXProperty()

Comment: Ну я так понял это так должно быть `Car1.layoutXProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());`

Comment: Зделал по примеру вот тепер ошибка.  Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: ImageView.layoutX : A bound value cannot be set.

Comment: Попробуйте впихнуть в Pane вместо AnchorPane

Comment: Зделал, тепер ошибок нету, но они почему-то звигаються назад и все больше не двигаються(

Comment: Кажется значение `progressBar` меняется от 0 до 1.0. вместо него попробуйте `updateValue(step.nextInt(10));` и `Car1.layoutXProperty().bind(task.valueProperty());`

Comment: такая же проблема(

Comment: Спасибо за ваше старанния, я сделал свое заданния, все таки использував thread пришлось переписать немного там.